# Algorithm for mapping objects of list without mapping to itself?

Tags: algorithms

I want to map objects of a list, to objects of that same list, randomly, without ever mapping any given object to itself.

So given a list of objects [a, b, c] valid maps would be, for example:

```
   a -> b,
   b -> c,
   c -> a
```

or

```
   a -> c,
   b -> a,
   c -> b
```

an invalid mapping would be:

```
   a -> a,
   b -> c,
   c -> b
```

I just cannot figure out how to implement such an algorithm.

(This is for a small Secret Santa app that I am building where each person will be assigned to buy gift to one of the other participants.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a cyclic permutation with no trivial cycles (i.e., the only cycle involves all elements) see [Sattolo's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Sattolo's_algorithm).

If you only want to avoid trivial cycles (but you are fine with cycles of length at least $2$), the mathematical object is called a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302057/generating-a-random-derangement

Since the probability  $p_n$ that a random permutation on $n$ elements is a derangement approaches $\frac{1}{e}$ as $n \to \infty$, you can easily get a randomized algorithm by simply generating a random permutations (e.g., using [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)) until you find a derangement.

The above bound is asymptotic but this works even for small values of $n$.
This is because the number of derangements on $n \ge 2$ elements is $!n = \left\lfloor \frac{n!}{e} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor$ (see,e.g., [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Hassani/hassani5.pdf)).
Since $p_n = \frac{!n}{n!}$, we can explicitly compute $p_2 = \frac{1}{2}$, $p_3 = \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$, and for $n \ge 4$ we have:

$$
p_n = \frac{!n}{n!} = \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n!}{e} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor}{n!}
> \frac{\frac{n!}{e} - \frac{1}{2}}{n!}
= \frac{1}{e} -\frac{1}{2 \cdot n!}
\ge \frac{1}{e} -\frac{1}{2 \cdot 24}
> \frac{1}{3}.
$$

This shows that, on average, you will not reject more than $2$ permutations. In general, the probability that you will look at more than $2t$ permutations will always be at most $(2/3)^{2t} \le 2^{-t}$.